# Android Search menu item disappears when pressing back button/collapsing search field

Tags: java, android, xml, android-actionbar, searchview

I'm using android SearchView to have a search button in my action bar. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OWmnYPX1uc) tutorial from Google Developers on YouTube, and added a few tweaks based on my own needs. However, whenever I exit the search field that comes up when clicking the button, the search button disappears!

Here is my onCreateOptionsMenu and onOptionsItemSelected functions

onCreateOptionsMenu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);


    return true;
}
```

onOptionsItemSelected:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            // TODO: settings activity
            break;
        case R.id.action_logout:
            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            break;
        case R.id.action_search:
            // Initialize everything here, because it produces a NullPointerException if initialized in onCreateOptionsMenu
            SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager)getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(this, SearchableActivity.class);
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName));

            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                    return false;
                }
            });
            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

And here's my menu_main.xml layout file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.magnus.inline.MainActivity">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_logout"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:title="@string/action_logout"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

And searchable.xml layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</searchable>
```

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KoiqW.png)

**EDIT:**

I noticed that the only time the search button disappears is when I've pressed the options button while in "search mode"(see the last image in link). I have a feeling that when the options menu is displayed, the "action_search" is somehow converted to a options menu item, instead of an action bar item (?). For anyone asking, whenever I try to call MenuItemCompat.getActionView() of a searchview MenuItem in the onCreateOptionsMenu function, my app just crashes and says that it tries to perform it on a null object reference.

Here's my activity_main.xml layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.magnus.inline.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat.Light"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you add an image of problem?

Comment: I copied your code into Android Studio and was unable to reproduce the problem. Are you sure you haven't left out any important code?

Comment: I'm also curious about this comment: "Initialize everything here, because it produces a NullPointerException if initialized in onCreateOptionsMenu". Perhaps this NPE is what's causing you trouble. FWIW, I've never had NPE setting up the `SearchView` inside `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

Comment: Now I added images. I will check again if I left something out

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of

```
app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
```

Change to

```
app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView
```